# Blank screen when accessing Kali Linux

Tags: applications, linux, vnc

I'm trying to access Linux Deploy, Kali Linux via a VNC Client on my Android phone. I could access it, but I get a blank screen.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what to do:

1. Use [Mobile SSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobileSSH.feng.gao) or [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux) to get to a virtual terminal
2. While in the terminal, install xrdp

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xrdp
   ```
3. Use [JuiceSSH](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sonelli.juicessh) on your Android to get graphical screen access

Comment: When I use sudo I get "No command 'sudo' found, did you mean: Command 'sum' from package 'coreutils' ..."

But when I enter, apt-get install xrdp I get "E: Unable to locate package xrdp"

Comment: Something is wrong with the setup.  sudo is built-in like whoami, and if you get an error when you put in  apt-get install xrdp  then there is likely something wrong with your repository files.  btw, If you can run apt-get install xrdp then you don't need the sudo command.  You're logged in as root.  No problem there.  But it should be able to find xrdp.  I have done this a dozen times and it always works.  Can you consider a clean install?  If you do, then you will still want to install xrdp and use Juice to access the GUI from Android.